# Make Tikz nodes look like text lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing

I want to create a figure where I have multiple nodes of text and make them look like a proper multi-line text.

Essentially I need two things:

1. Figure out the proper node distance to use (I got this by dumping \the\baselineskip).
2. Arrange all nodes to use that distance.

I can make this work if every node has only one line:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees,positioning,arrows, fit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \begin{scope}[
                    node distance   = 18.0pt,
            ]
            \node[rectangle, font=\huge] (Title) {Title};
            \node[inner sep=0, font=\Large, align=left] (start) [below=of Title] {Hello};
            \node[inner sep=0, font=\Large, align=left] (mid) [below=of start.west,anchor=west] {Hi};
            \node[inner sep=0,font=\Large, align=left] (end) [below=of mid.west,anchor=west] {Bye};
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However if there are nodes with multiple lines then there are overlaps:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees,positioning,arrows, fit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \begin{scope}[
                    node distance   = 18.0pt,
            ]
            \node[rectangle, font=\huge] (Title) {Title};
            \node[inner sep=0, font=\Large, align=left] (start) [below=of Title] {Hello};
            \node[inner sep=0, font=\Large, align=left] (mid) [below=of start.west,anchor=west] {Hi};
            \node[inner sep=0,font=\Large, align=left] (end) [below=of mid.west,anchor=west] {Bye \\ Bye \\ Bye};
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously I want to avoid splitting all text to single-line nodes and I don't want to manually use yshift to fix the distances.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Assuming you know that you can write in a given node multiple nodes, I wonder what you like to achieve. BTW, are you aware of `shapes.multipart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you position the nodes relative to appropriate anchors, no overlaps happen.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \begin{scope}[
                    node distance   = 6pt,
            ]
            \node[rectangle, font=\huge,anchor=south west] (Title) {Title};
            \node[inner sep=0, font=\Large, align=left] (start) [below=of
            Title.south west,anchor=north west] {Hello};
            \node[inner sep=0, font=\Large, align=left] (mid) [below=of
            start.south west,anchor=north west] {Hi};
            \node[inner sep=0,font=\Large, align=left] (end) 
            [below=of mid.south west,anchor=north west] {Bye \\ Bye \\ Bye};
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I am not sure I understand the purpose. Are you by chance looking for `shapes.multipart` or `matrix`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I think I need different nodes because later on I want to format some of them in a different way, but I'll definitely take a look at your suggestions.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can connect nodes in chain:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain = going below left,
    node distance = 6pt and 0pt
                        ]
        \node[font=\huge,anchor=south west] (Title) {Title};
        \begin{scope}[every node/.append style = {
                font=\Large, align=left, inner sep=0pt,
                on chain, anchor=north west}
                      ]
        \node[below=of Title.south west] {Hello};
        \node {Hi};
        \node {Bye \\ Bye \\ Bye};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]